# Query out a record based on other conditions in the table (Choosing records)

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically I have a table in a stored procedure with patient id's, care provider id's, times seen, got kcode, a date seen and an empty column which says whether the doctor got the correct kcode. The doctor will get the kcode for a patient if they have seen the patient the most times. If that doctor and another doctor has seen them the same amount of times, it relies on the earliest date to choose.

How would I write some queries to insert a 1 next to the row with the doctor who got the kcode for each patient? Below is a picture of the results I get when I query out the table from the stored procedure.

This is the result when I use the Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT allCodes.PTNT_ID, allCodes.CP_ID FROM tmp_kcodes allCodes
JOIN BILL b ON b.PTNT_ID = allCodes.PTNT_ID
WHERE b.STS_CD = 'P'
ORDER BY PTNT_ID;
```

The 'P' in the bill table is just looking for paid bills.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a bit trickier but if you write a few derived tables into your select from the sproc you should be able to identify the two mismatch criteria: 1) times seen is greater for a cp that didn't get the kcode 2) times seen is equal and earliest date is < the earliest date of the assigned cp.

```
select
    ptnt_id
    --Assigned CP values
    , assigned_cp
    , assigned_times_seen
    , assigned_got_kcode
    , assigned_earliest_date_seen
    --Unassigned CP values
    , unassigned_cp
    , unassigned_times_seen
    , unassigned_got_kcode
    , unassigned_earliest_date_seen
    , case 
        when (times_seen_mismatch = 1 or earliest_date_mismatch = 1)
        then 0
        else 1
    end as correct_kcode
from
    (
        select
            ptnt_id
            , kcode_assigned.cp_id as assigned_cp
            , kcode_zero.cp_id as unassigned_cp
            --case to determine where times_seen of assigned cp 
            --is less than that of an unassigned cp
            , case
                when kcode_zero.times_seen > kcode_assigned.times_seen
                then 1
                else 0
            end as times_seen_mismatch
            --case to determine where times_seen of assigned cp 
            --equals times_seen of unassigned cp and the unassigned cp
            --saw the patient on an earlier date than the assigne cp
            , case
                when kcode_zero.times_seen = kcode_assigned.times_seen
                    and kcode_zero.earliest_date_seen < kcode_assigned.earliest_date_seen
                then 1
                else 0
            end as earliest_date_mismatch
            --Assigned CP fields
            , kcode_assigned.times_seen as assigned_times_seen
            , kcode_assigned.got_kcode as assigned_got_kcode
            , kcode_assigned.earliest_date_seen as assigned_earliest_date_seen
            --Unassigned CP fields
            , kcode_zero.times_seen as unassigned_times_seen
            , kcode_zero.got_kcode as unassigned_got_kcode
            , kcode_zero.earliest_date_seen as unassigned_earliest_date_seen
        from
            --derived table to return only those 
            --records where kcode assigned
            (
                select
                    ptnt_id
                    , cp_id
                    , times_seen
                    , got_kcode
                    , earliest_date_seen
                from
                    [your table]
                where
                    got_kcode > 0
            ) kcode_assigned
            left outer join
                --derived table to return only those
                --records where kcode was not assigned
                (
                    select
                        ptnt_id
                        , cp_id
                        , times_seen
                        , got_kcode
                        , earliest_date_seen
                    from
                        [your table]
                    where
                        got_kcode = 0
                ) kcode_zero
                    on kcode_assigne.ptnt_id = kcode_zero.ptnt_id
    ) validate
where
    1=1
    and (times_seen_mismatch = 1 or earliest_date_mismatch = 1)
```

Comment: I'm essentially ignoring that column because it is used to compare later against the ones that should get it. The GOT_KCODE column is a list of who was assigned the kcode (if the number is anything but 0) but i'm trying to look for the errors in the assigned values and see where there were assigned but should not have gotten it.

Comment: What you wrote is useful when comparing whether the assignment was correct or not. I need to write the query that mathematical checks if they got it right and put a 1 or a 0 in another column. Between each patient, the doctor who has seen that patient the most should get the kcode. If they are equal (lets say they both have a 1), it should look for the earliest date.

Comment: From your query i got this http://imgur.com/LKD5JSc
What exactly is this showing me?

Comment: im trying to compare rows and columns

Comment: Where times_seen_mismatch = 1 the unassigned_cp has seen the patient more times than the assigned cp.  where earliest_date_mismatch = 1 the unassigned_cp has seen the patient the same number of times as the assigned cp and saw the patient earlier than the assigned cp

Comment: http://imgur.com/sAN4A3d This right here is a case of where the code was incorrectly assigned. The times seen is the same, the date for the first doctor is earlier but the code was assigned to the other doctor. I just want the 1's and 0's placed as i have shown

Comment: The above image is essentially how i want it formatted. Tack on the first piece of code you gave me before you edited it and then thats exactly what i need. I do appreciate the help youve given me so far

Comment: Do you want the ptnt_id, cp_id, times_seen, got_kcode, earliest_date_seen from the assigned CP or the unassigned CP?

Comment: I want both CP there, the 1 should just indicate which CP should get the kcode

Comment: There should be a assigned_kcode_flag column and a calculated_kcode_flag column with all the patients and CP. The calculated kcode flag column should indicate which should get the kcode based on the times seen and the earliest date. The assigned kcode flag column is just that piece of code you had before (if get_kcode is greater than 1 then assign a 1). Or even better, put the CP_ID of the incorrect assignment, and the CP_ID of the correct assignment instead of 1's and 0's

Comment: In the code I provided you could replace the 0 in the top select with the unassigned_cp field.  That would return the CP that should be assigned to the patient.

Comment: I'm just confused because there are a lot of PTNT_ID's missing and there shouldn't be this many mismatches between the assigned and calculated CP_ID's

Comment: There is a where clause at the bottom of the query that is filtering the results to only those records that are deemed invalid.  You can comment out the very last line to return all the Ptnt_ids.  As for the number of invalid records - the fields for both assigned and unassigned CPs are returned so you can see why each record is deemed invalid...

Comment: I dont understand what the assigned and unassigned CP columns are

Comment: the assigned_cp is the CP_ID that has a got_kcode value > 0.  Unassigned is CP_ID that has got_kcode = 0

Answer (score 0):

What would you like your results to look like? Do you want a new column next to the CP_ID that would have a one in it if there is any number beside 0 in the Got_Kcode row?

Comment: In the very end i would like to update my table stored procedure so that the CORRECT_KCODE table has a 1 where the doctor got the kcode and a 0 where they didnt.